# Acer Aspire Revo R3600: One long, two short beeps while booting, with no video

Tags: bios, acer-aspire, acer-revo

I have a Revo R3600 to repair and the PC starts to boot, but immediately beeps, followed by a slight pause, then two short beeps that are close together.

There's no output on the monitor at any time.

I have tried searching online for Acer beep codes, but am unsuccessful - any ideas what the fault might be on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This beep code usually indicates a broken video adapter.

If the computer has a video card, replace it.  If the computer has integrated graphics, the motherboard may be broken.

Comment: Hmm. I was worried that someone would say that.  The graphics card is embedded, meaning that the board would be dead, which is a shame as it is a small (compact) media-PC. :o(

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that the long-short-short beep pattern is Morse for, "D" (=display).

In my case it was the same sort of problem but all it took was to pull and reseat the Video display card.  If you are going to do this, make sure dust does not get in the slot. Clean the inside of the computer first, then remove and reseat it being careful of static charges.